# Are there multiple translations for 不上边?

Tags: translation

Trying to translate this: 始终是碰不上边的...

From the beginning, not able to meet (in agreement) with those above?

I searched on "不上边" in 百度 and it seems there are multiple ways to interpret it - position-wise and for example, this: 世界杯与穷人沾不上边. Here top is not top as in position, but priority? Does 不上边 have different meanings?

Here's the context for the first phrase:

Connie:     龃龉，我们看它的汉字。这两个字呢，都有一个，牙齿的齿… …它的左边。

徐州:     那跟牙齿有关系。

Connie:     啊，有关系。龃龉呢是说，牙齒上下，对不起。

徐州:     啊…

Connie:     嗯，就是它对不上，就是很错乱的。

徐州:     啊…唉…

Connie:     看起来很难看吧。

徐州:     对的。

Connie:     啊， 所以它用来比喻呢，啊， 双方的意见不和。

徐州:     嗯。观念啊、关点啊、始终是碰**不上边**的。

Connie:     嗯，对。

徐州:     好。

Connie:     所以我们会说龃龉不断或者发生龃龉。就是两个人产生意见不和你可以说发生龃龉。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's two things going on; a verb (碰边 or 沾边) and an auxiliary verb (不上) inserted in the middle.

碰边, [沾边](http://baike.baidu.com/view/2730787.htm) literally mean "to touch the edge", which is a metaphor for relationship. [不上](http://www.zdic.net/c/d/142/310430.htm) means "unable to" in this context (similar to 不到 or 不得). So altogether, 碰不上边 means "unrelated".

Comment: I would probably refer to 不上 as a verb infix, rather than an aux verb. Anyway, terminology aside, this answer is right on the mark.

Comment: @deutschZuid sure; I'm no linguist so if you think the terminology can be corrected, please go ahead and make an edit.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there multiple translations for 不上边?

The related phrases are:

1）无关

2）不着调

3）牛头不对马嘴

Comment: haha, I like #3, very interesting!

Answer (score 1):

碰不上边(cannot touch each other's edge)=对不上(cannot match each other)=不合(cannot agree with each other)

不知道词源是怎么样的，但是你想象有两个盘子，连边都碰不上，怎么可能合得上呢？
(How can they match each other (like we are doing a jigsaw) even if their edge cannot touch each other?)

说 两个人（意见）不合，就是说they don't agree with each other.